# Javascript - React native - how to put in a TextInput and Text in the same row

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, styles, stylesheet

I'm working on React native and Expo XDE on my Android and I want that these Texts - "username" and the "password" will be to the right to their TextInputs (because I write in Hebrew language), so it will be in two rows and not on the screenshot below.
This is the code:

```html
  <View style={styles.container}>
 <Text > Travel </Text>

        {/* <View style={styles.row}>
      <View style={styles.inputWrap}> */}

        <Text> Username </Text>

        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ username: text })}
          value={this.state.username}
        />

          <Text> Password </Text>
       
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })}
          value={this.state.password}
          secureTextEntry={true}
        />
```

[This is how its look now: the main screen with login or register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvHtp.png)

I'd tried these styles codes but it didn't work, it made a huge mess up on the android and everything just flew:

```js
input: {
    height: 40,
    width: 180,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1
  },

  inputWrap: {
    flex: 1,
    borderColor: "#cccccc",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 10
  },

  row: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row"
  }
```

I also want to design the headline "Travel" on the top but I
 haven't succeed at all after so many times, it stayed the same.

Can you please help me with those issues ? if more details are needed please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your Text and TextInput into another View which flex direction is row and vertically centered. This code works for me.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>Travel</Text>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>Username</Text>
      <TextInput style={{width: 200}}/>
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>Password</Text>
      <TextInput style={{width: 200}}/>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: Thank you @Sedat Öztürk,  now the username has moved too much to the left becasue it is longer than the word "password" in Hebrew.  2) to make it more pleasing to the eye how can I do spaces between rows like <p> </p> in javascript ? I tries "&nbsp" but it made me an error.

Comment: For 2, you can add marginVertical to View styles.

Comment: For 1 you can edit Text's style with same width and textAlign: 'left'
if this solution works, please upvote and accept my answer :)